# Dog charges at other dogs

Tags: dogs, aggression, socializing, training

I have a Boston terrier, female, 2 years old. We've been socializing her ever since she's been a puppy and she's generally well behaved. She sometimes tends to be stubborn, but is a good dog overall.

However, there is one type of behavior that I would really like to correct with her: when we are outside, leashed or not, and she sees another dog, regardless of the sex, size, or breed, at first she freezes and looks at a dog for about 10 seconds, and then charges like mad (she is really, I mean really, fast dog). If the other dog is big, it let's her come and she usually just runs past it and then makes a full circle only to make another go. But, if the other dog is small or has low confidence, it reads it as an attack and gets defensive, and the dog owner almost always reads it as my dog being aggressive.

It feels like she is **super** excited when she sees another dog. And whilst this may appear as an cheerful character, it is actually quite burdening. Has anyone had any experience on this subject? How do I explain my dog to take it down a notch?